# Turn off Splash screen after initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Currently for a website, I have index.html, about.html, etc. The splash screen loads on index.html, but I don't want it to appear anymore after initially loading on the home screen. (even going from about page -> index)

This is the jquery I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".splash").is(":visible")) {
        $(".wrapper").css({"opacity":"0"});
    }

    $(".splash-arrow").click(function() {
        $(".splash").slideUp("800", function() {
            $(".wrapper").delay(100).animate({"opacity":"1.0"}, 800);
        });
    });
});
```

It is connected to index.html. Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem?

Comment: are you writing a single page app, without page refresh?

Comment: @Ozrix no, its not a single page app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the splash screen only when the user visits `index.html` for the first time you need to store that information somewhere. Typically this is done via either `LocalStorage` or `Cookies`. For the latter there is an excellent library on github available:

[js-cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Keep in mind though that Cookies are sent back to the server with each and every request you make.

Sample Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof Cookies.get("seen_splash") !== "undefined") {
        // Insert code to show the splash screen here
    }

    // Set the cookie for 365 days.
    $(".splash-arrow").on("click", function() {
        Cookies.set("seen_splash", true, { expires: 365 });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, i attempted to implement js cookies like you suggested and except when I print out the cookies with console.log after the set "seen_splash" to true, it's still undefined. any idea why this might be the case?  https://jsfiddle.net/r0Ly0s76/

Comment: This happens because the condition `if (typeof Cookies.get("seen_splash") !== "undefined") {...}` checks if a cookie has been previously set. Thing is that you set the cookie in line 1 to an arbitrary string value, meaning the cookie does exist now and the existence check always fails. You only need to set the cookie when the user has seen the splash, not somewhere else. Moreover there is no need to delete the cookie before setting it again, just overwrite it

Comment: @user3784193 if you feel like this post answers your question, it'd be awesome of you to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I fixed the things you suggested, but line 12 continues to return undefined when I run it. Do you know this is happening?

Comment: @user3784193 Perhaps you did not run your code on a webserver. Cookies are not allowed if the html is opened via the `file://` protocol. Jsfiddle won't work either, because setting cookies is not allowed there.